# Riemann Integrable Map Proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and suppose $\forall x\in [a,b]$ $f(x)\geq 0$ with  $\int^{b}_{a}f =0$ then $f(x)=0$ for each x in $[a,b]$.

My proof:
Suppose for some $c\in [a,b]$ we have $f(c)>0$. Let $x\in [a,b]$ so for $\epsilon=\frac{f(c)}{2}$ there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that whenever $x\in (c-\delta_1,c+\delta_2)$ we have $f(x)>\frac{f(c)}{2}$.
Now we observe that if $(c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)$ is contained in $[a,b]$ then we would have $c-\frac{\delta_1}{2}\geq a$ and $c+\frac{\delta_1}{2}\leq b$. Therefore, we can break the integral into pieces and observe that $\int^{c+\frac{\delta_1}{2}}_{c-\frac{\delta_1}{2}}f$ $\geq$ $\frac{f(c)}{2}\delta_1$ $>0$, and consequently $\int^{b}_{a}f>0$. If $(c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)$ is not contained in $[a,b]$ then $c-\delta_1<a$ or $c+\delta_1>b$. Without loss of generality, suppose $c-\delta_1<a$ $<c+\delta_1$, as f is continuous, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that $c-\delta\geq a$ and $c+\delta\leq b$ therefore we can repeat the same argument as above, and yield the same conclusion.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Mostly correct. If $c=b$, for example, then there is no interval of the form that you wrote. You can avoid this problem and the need for the last paragraph by saying "there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that whenever $x\in (c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)\cap[a,b]$ ..." Adjust the rest accordingly and clarify that this intersection is an interval (not necessarily open or closed) with positive length.

Comment: If $f(c)>0$, you can assume $c\in (a,b)$. Thus, you can also find $\delta > 0$ such that $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\subset [a,b]$ and $f(x)\ge\frac{f(c)}2$ for all $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$. Then you don't need the separation into cases.

Comment: @amsmath thanks!